# ImportError: No module named backends when uising python-social-auth when upgrading to Django 1.9

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am upgrading my project from Django 1.8 to Django 1.9 and when I run my server using `python manage.py runserver` i am getting error in my views like

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/projectfolder/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/projectfolder/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/projectfolder/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/projectfolder/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/projectfolder/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/projectfolder/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/projectfolder/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/projectfolder/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/projectfolder/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/projectfolder/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/projectfolder/projectrespos/dev-1.8/mcam/server/mcam/mcam/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    from crm.views import *
  File "/home/projectfolder/projectrespos/dev-1.8/mcam/server/mcam/crm/views.py", line 63, in <module>
    from core.views import (CustomAuthMixin, CustomAdminMixin, JSONResponseMixin,
  File "/home/projectfolder/projectrespos/dev-1.8/mcam/server/mcam/core/views.py", line 477, in <module>
    from social.apps.backends import get_backends
ImportError: No module named backends
```

core/views.py

```
from social.apps.backends import get_backends
def get_auth_backends():
    backends = get_backends()
    return [(name, title, backends.get(name)) for name, title in settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_ACTIVE_BACKENDS.items() if name in backends]
```

In my settings.py folder

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    . . . . ,
    . . . . ,
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.backends.pipeline.social_auth.social_auth_user',
    'social.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
    'core.social.pipeline.redirect_to_signup_form',
    'core.social.pipeline.create_user',
    'social.backends.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.backends.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
)
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuthBackend',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleBackend',
    'subscription.authentication.SubscriptionBackend',
    
)    
SOCIAL_AUTH_ACTIVE_BACKENDS = {
    "google-oauth2": "Google",
}
```

In my mcam/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    
    url(r'', include('social.apps.django_app.urls')),
]
```

Here my

```
Django == 1.9
Python == 2.7.12
python-social-auth == 0.2.19
```

And when trying to import get_backends i am getting error now how can i resolve it ?

Is my settings.py file (means how can i include my python-social-auth) and project urls.py is correct ?

And also how can I solve my issue in views.py ?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802287/8401179

Comment: Thank you but my doubt is previously i used django-social-auth but now i am using python-social-auth so from that how can i import my backends ? And according to the link you shared ,already 'rest_framework' is wriiten in my INSTALLED_APPS